# Chain Multiple Objects into parent Object Django

Tags: python, django

I am working on an app in django and i am wondering if there is a method to chain multiple objects into 1 parent.

For example, I have -query_1-, -query_2-, and I would like to put the objects that those queries return into one -parent_object- to pass to the template, which I can access on the template side like {{ parent_object.query_1.field }}, is this possible or is there a way to achieve a similar effect ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from itertools import chain
chained_qs = chain(qs1, qs2)
```